# How to highlight selected text in a Python Gtk TextView

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3, pygtk, glade

I recently ported a Python application from python2 to python3, moving to `Gtk+ 3.18`. In the python2 version, when I click inside the text area and move the mouse, the selected text is automatically highlighted. Similarly, I click on a word, that word is highlighted. However, in python3, I don't see any highlighting of the selected area. I am able to copy the area, so I know it's selected, but there's no visual highlighting applied.  I'm using Glade to define some of the window settings, but I haven't changed anything from the python2 version.

I was wondering if I need to explicitly enable highlighting of text, or add this manually. It seems like this would be a common feature, but I can't find any instructions to enable it or other answers on SO. Any help would be appreciated- thank you!

python2 selected text:
[image]

same text in python3, not highlighted:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding a background color for the SELECTED state: `override_background_color(gtk.StateFlags.SELECTED, rgba)`.